# How to create a generic class that can take many parameters

Tags: c#, design-patterns, polymorphism

Okay, so I am creating a Utility AI framework. For this to work I need a class that can change a lot depending on the situation I am sure, and I hope that there is a way to use polymorphism or some sort of design pattern to solve my issue.

Let me show you what I mean

I have an action for the sake of example let's say I have the following action **Attack Target**

This action can have a number of considerations that will vary a lot but all implement the same interface:

```
   public interface IConsideration
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   A unique named identifier for this consideration.
    /// </summary>
    string NameId { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   The weight of this consideration.
    /// </summary>
    float Weight { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   If true, then the output of the associated evaluator is inverted, in effect, inverting the
    ///   consideration.
    /// </summary>
    bool IsInverted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Calculates the utility given the specified context.</summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns>The utility.</returns>
    float Consider<T>(BaseAiContext context, T value);

}
```

*The above is my current implementation it doesn't really solve the issue I have*

As you can see the "most" important method of this interface is the `Consider`

and here lies the issue preferably I should be able to pass data to this class in a way that I can control.

For the sake of example let's say one consideration I have is **Move To Location** here I want to send the following parameters:

- Location of target
- Weapon type (ranged / melee)
- location list

The above is just an example to prove my point. There is another issue with this - how can I pass the correct parameters when I finally have them? say that I have the following code:

```
public List<IConsideration> considerations;
float targetDistance = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < considerations.Count; i++)
{
    float AxisScore = considerations[i].Consider(BaseAiContext,targetDistance );
}
```

Since I have to use the `Interface` type I am unable to know exactly which values to parse as parameters.

To sum it up:

**How can i "parameterize" my class in a generic way?**

**How can I distinguish these parameterizations so I can provide a consideration with the correct values?**

Comment: Sounds like you really need a generic abstract base class and a concrete derived class

Comment: One of the patterns is to change your responsibilities from the caller to the consumer eg. instead of passing in the "correct" parameters to the method, you should pass in an object containing the information and then the consumer deal with  it.

Comment: @Tomek Could you give a code example of this?

Comment: You can have a dictionary or a list of your settings and each implementation of your interface will pull out the necessary keys this way you only pass around a list/dictionary/class/struct (whatever data type you decide) into it.

Comment: @Tomek But how will i know what keys needs to be filled?

Comment: some pseudo example ```var settings = new Dictionary<string,object>(){"TARGET",[x,y],"WEAPONTYPE","melee" }```  then change your interface to accept a settings object ```float Consider<T>(BaseAiContext context, Dictionary<string,object> options);``` then you can call it ```considerations[i].Consider(BaseAiContext,settings);```

Comment: @MarcRasmussen you have somewhere a ```class``` which implements ```IConsideration``` that class should know what it needs? if you have eg, a MoveToLocation implementation then you know that this needs the destination point and what ever vs. AttackEnemey which will need a different set like the destination of the enemy plus the weapon type etc. i don't know .. i cant guess the rest of your project :-D

Comment: @Tomek That is correct is it possible that you could try and post an answer with a very very simplified implementation of what you mean i would really like to see the looping through of considerations as shown in my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarcRasmussen requested an example

As each implementation of your interface might consume different sets of arguments one way to solve it would be to kind of have key-value storage like a dictionary.

There are plenty of improvements to be made like, using ENUMS instead of strings, and having a static manager class for things like that to add/modify/remove settings.

This is a quick example and not tested, with the information available.

```cs
public class MoveToTarget : IConsideration
{

   //method is changed to have generic return type and accept dictionary for settings
   float Consider(BaseAiContext context, Dictionary<string,object> settings){
     
      //make sure required keys exist  

      if(!settings.ContainsKey("DESTINATION"))
          throw new ApplicationException("Missing key DESTINATION");
      if(!settings.ContainsKey("SPEED"))
          throw new ApplicationException("Missing key SPEED");

         // retrieve you required settings, at this stage since you cast an object, you should check the type ... this problem would be solved if you have (as further below mentioned) a specific settings class for all your implementations. this way you ensure type safety too.

         Point destination =  (Point)settings["DESTINATION"];
         float speed = (float)settings["SPEED"];

         // and perform whatever logic you need. etc.
   }

}

public List<IConsideration> considerations;

//this should be probably static and globally available (?) probably better to have a singleton manager class to deal with that.

Dictionary<string,object> Settings = new Dictionary<string,object>()
{ 
   {"SPEED", 1.0f},
   {"RANDOM", new Random()},
   {"DESTINATION", new Point()},
   {"XYZ", "XYZ"},
   //etc.
}

//use foreach unless you need to have access to the index
foreach(var consideration in considerations)
{
    float AxisScore = consideration.Consider(BaseAiContext, Settings);
}
```

some other improvements could be to have a specific settings class for each of your implementations like `MoveToTargetSettings` and then instead of havin ambiguous "KEYS" in a dictionary you can retrieve the specific settings by its class etc. like `var settings = settingDictionary["MoveToTargetSettins"] as MoveToTargetSettings`

I think for anything better more details are required, happy to discuss and answer any further questions outside of SO as that will be off-topic :)